# Code to html converter

Tags: javascript, java, c#, code-formatting, code-conversion

What is good free tool (both online, offline) to convert code (could be also html code) text snippet (already formatted) to html with code highlighting (keywords at least) and keep original formatting (as html snippet already) to make it possible to insert to blog?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress, I can recommend [this extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/). It should be exactly what you are looking for.

Just an example, taken from the page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had good experience [google-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) - the same engine they use here at SO. Based on javascript, should be pretty easy to integrate, even in content management systems (did it with Plone)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in visual studio it self. create empty html file and copy the code whatever you want. then paste it in to design view of the above created temporary html file. it will generate the formatting with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Almost sounds legit.  If Design View doesn't exist, right click the HTML and Open With WebForms Editor.  But pasting code into Design View just turns to black text.  I wish you'd revisit this though if it still works in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/) which works quite well on BlogSpot.